# time-out while trying to download public keys

Tags: package-management

Almost every time I try to add a new software source, I get an error:

```
james@james-GA-890GPA-UD3H:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:flozz/flozz
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /etc/apt/secring.gpg --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 879E176037576C38DA61862BD2BF771175034BEC
gpg: requesting key 75034BEC from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
?: keyserver.ubuntu.com: Connection timed out
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect: Connection timed out
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
james@james-GA-890GPA-UD3H:~$
```

Am I doing something wrong? I'm using cut & paste to avoid typos.

Comment: Do you still have an active internet connection when you are trying?  Is this for all repositorys or just a few?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy/firewall ?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure :)

Answer (score 2):

Most probably the port (11371) used for downloading the GPG key from the Ubuntu keyserver is blocked by your ISP/firewall. Unfortunately all the alternate keyservers use the same port.

Hopefully keyserver.ubuntu.com will start using a standard port for this in the future...

Comment: Unfortunately the keyserver sometimes is simply overloaded.

Comment: This happens every time I try to add a repository using the method "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:" far as I can determine my Modem/Firewall is not set to block port (11371) and I don't use a proxy